# How do remote repositories in Maven work?

Tags: maven

Just started learning Maven in 15 minutes ago! and have a silly question:

If we want to pull from a remote repo, are there TWO places in POM.XML that we need to change?
My understanding is that we should do two things:

1: Define the remote repo location in REPOSITORIES tag  and then,

2: Define the specific dependency in Dependencies tag

Did I understand it correct? Is it a good practice ?

I was following these tutorials: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-do-download-from-remote-repository-maven/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding of dependencies is required but try to avoid adding of repositories:
http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/

Here are best books about maven and infrastructure around it:
http://www.sonatype.com/Support/Books